# Which customer has bought 4 or more items in our store?

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

Which customer has bought 4 or more items in our store?

```
SELECT cutomer.cusName, COUNT(itemName) AS 'Number of items'
FROM customer INNER JOIN store
ON customer.cusID = store.cusID
GROUP BY cutomer.cusName;
```

I'm not sure how to output which customer has bought 4 or more items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `HAVING` clause to get the customers who bought 4 or more items

```
SELECT cutomer.cusName, COUNT(itemName) AS 'Number of items'
FROM customer INNER JOIN store
ON customer.cusID = store.cusID
GROUP BY cutomer.cusName
HAVING count(itemName) >=4
```